# Implementation of vector class in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, math, delphi-2010, records

How would you go about creating a vector class in Delphi? I would prefer to put all math related stuff into a DLL. Should I use a record or a class implementing an interface?

Pros of record approach:

- Fast and lightweight
- Value type
- Operator overloading

Cons of record approach:

- Implementation cannot be hidden in DLL (no inheritance, so no abstract base class for the DLL interface possible)
- Problems with records as properties of classes (`Class.VectorProp.X := 42`)

What do you think?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to put the math stuff in a DLL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your priorities.

If performance is a top priority, go for records. But if implementation hiding is top, go for interfaces.

But why not use a package so you can both use static and dynamic linking if you want it. Of course, a DLL is prefered if the code is to be used by other languages, a DLL is a better aproach.

Botom line, the requirements and their relative priority determine the implementation.

Comment: +1 Accepted. I assumed that there is no "right" way. I'll have to think about my priority here. Thanks!

Comment: The right way depend on your requirements. Sometimes they are conflicting so you have to be creative.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used either of these, but they could save you some time.

1. [SDL MathPack](http://www.lohninger.com/mathpack.html) - not sure if you would have to pay for it
2. [Jedi Math](http://jedimath.sourceforge.net) - looks like the project has been abandoned, but you should check it out anyway.  If your not doing anything crazy it will probably work for you.

Comment: Thanks even though this is not an answer to my question.